# How to set a default value for a form in every update?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to set a default value in a form and it will be reset as `approval = False` in every update. I tried something but it did not work it doesn't change. How can I fixed it?

**forms.py**

```
class UpdateDoaTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    approval = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                  initial=False,
                                  label='Approved',
                                  widget=forms.HiddenInput()
                                  )

    class Meta:
        model = DoaTable
        fields = ('limit', 'approval')
```

**views.py**

```
def update_limit(request, id):
    limiting = get_object_or_404(DoaTable, id=id)
    form = UpdateDoaTableForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=limiting)
    limiting_item = DoaTable.objects.filter(id=id)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('approvals:update_limit_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'limiting_item': limiting_item,
    }

    return render(request, 'limitUpdate.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class DoaTable(models.Model):
    ...
    approval = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: So even if the instance of a bound form has `approval=True` you want the form field to default to `False`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes. It should be False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit my code and it is working now.:

**views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
    update_form = form.save(commit=False)
    update_form.approval = False
    update_form.save()
    return redirect('approvals:update_limit_list')
```